# i am trying to find the reverse of the string

Tags: java, arrays

i made a program in which i have to find the reverse of the string .i found the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>     at mypackage.Reverse1.main(Reverse1.java:18)

following is my code

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String s ="saima";
    //first we cal length of string
    int L= s.length();
    //now i declchararry of given string length
    char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
    // i decl new arry
    char[] array=new char[L];

    int j=L;

    for(int k=0; k<L; k++)
    {
        array[k]= charArray[j];
        j--;


    }
    String output1 = new String(array);
    System.out.println("output1 : " + output1);

}
```

Comment: Did you Google the exception in order to make an effort to understand what it is and why it happens?

Answer (score 4):

In `charArray[j]`, j is initially out of bounds, since you initialize it to the size of the String.

If you change

```
int j=L;
```

to

```
int j=L-1;
```

It will work.

Or you can get rid of the `j` variable :

```
for(int k=0; k<L; k++)
{
    array[k] = charArray[L-1-k];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String s ="saima";

    System.out.println("output1 : " + new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());

}
```